# How to display ForeignKey's value in the Grid

Tags: c#, winforms, list, gridview

I am using ADO.NET EF to do DB activities. I have User and Permission table, and I have another UserPermissionRelation which holds links between Users and Relations. The link is made by foreign key.

UserPermissionRelation table is like below

```
 | ID  |  UserId  |  RelationID
 --------------------------------
 | 1   |  1       |  5
 | 2   |  2       |  7
```

I am using Devexpress GridControl and I would like to list the UserPermissionRelation table in the grid but I want to list name of User and Relation instead of their Ids.

here is my code

```
userPermissionList = MainForm.db.UserPermissionRelation.ToList();
gc.DataSource = userPermissionList;
```

and here is a snapshot that will more clue...

[image]

How can I list the names that is in sublist in the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a RepositoryItemLookupEdit within the GridControl.

2) Then fill the RepositoryItemLookupEdit with a list of users.

```
var users = MainForm.db.Users.ToList();
userRepositoryItemLookupEdit.DataSource = users;
userRepositoryItemLookupEdit.DisplayMember = nameof(User.Username);
userRepositoryItemLookupEdit.ValueMember = nameof(User.Id);
userRepositoryItemLookUpEdit.NullText = "";
```

3) Bind the RepositoryItemLookupEdit to the user column.

```
gridView.Columns["someColumnKey"].ColumnEdit = userRepositoryItemLookupEdit;
```

You can then change the underlying Id with the help of a lookup control, but you will always see the username.

Comment: It runs but it says "EditValue is null" in the grid.

Comment: Just set userRepositoryItemLookupEdit.NullText property to an empty string or whatever you want to display in the grid. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Well, "EditValue is null" is the default behavior of a DevExpress Lookup control if the underlying value is null or DBNull.Value. Setting the `NullText` property is the only possibility you have. Did you try setting a different string? Maybe they are not allowing an empty string. But I'm really sure it works.